# Trouble: QWebView with local html which includes local JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qwebview

I am developing an application which loads a local html inside a QWebView in this way:

```
ui->webView->setUrl(QUrl("qrc:/index.html"));
```

and the page is correctly loaded **but** not the JavaScript. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="utils.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test_func();"/>
  </body>
 </html>
```

so, in utils.js I have test_func() but it does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: As you load page from resource file, could you show us your resource tree structure to be sure `util.js` is loaded. You can also enable `QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled` to inspect your page.

Comment: dude, the resource tree hint has been a good deal. I've added utils.js to resources.qrc and now it works! ;)